# Swagger-php with Swagger-ui not working with Basic Authentication

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui

I use swagger-ui and swagger-json generated with swagger-php. I m not able to do a basic auth to use my endpoint. I m able to get the swagger json file from my application but not to use exposed endpoint. I don't see what i m misunderstanding. If someone could show me a full example with basic auth in swagger 2.0 ?
CORS is enabled and totally working. Swagger-ui is running on localhost:3000 with nodejs and my application is running php with nginx on localhost:80.

I use swagger-ui-dist 3.14.1 that is compatible with swagger 2.0 (swagger-php is 2.0)

```
3.14.1 | 2018-05-04 | 2.0, 3.0 | tag v3.14.1
```

I m using theses SWG comments in my controllers to use basicAuth, (server-side)

```
/**
 *  @SWG\SecurityScheme(
  *      securityDefinition="basicAuth",
  *      name="authorization",
  *      type="basic",
  *      scheme="http"
  *  )
  */
```

and this comments

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     description="Get all catalog",
 *     path="/ott/catalogs",
 *     produces={"application/json"},
 *     security = {"basicAuth"},
 *     @SWG\Response(response="200", description="Get all catalogs"),
 *     @SWG\Response(response="401",description="You are not authorized")
 *     )
 * )
 */
```

Here is my client-side code:

```
 window.onload = function() {
         // Build a system
       const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
         url: "http://ott/ott/tools/swagger",
         host: 'ott',
         basePath: 'ott/',
         schemes: 'http',
         enableCORS: true,
         dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
         deepLinking: true,
         validatorUrl:null,
         presets: [
           SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
           SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
         ],
         plugins: [
           SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
         ],
         layout: "StandaloneLayout",
         requestInterceptor: (req) => {
             if (req.loadSpec) {
                 let hash = btoa("*******" + ":" + "********");
                 req.headers.Authorization = "Basic " + hash;
             }
             return req
         },
           onComplete : () => {
             ui.preauthorizeBasic("basicAuth","*******","*******")
           }
       });
       window.ui = ui
```

When i click to the lock, i have the first error in my console and then when i try to get my catalogs i get a 401 - not authorized because the Basic Authentication header is not sent.

[image: capture du 2018-05-07 16-44-38]

Comment: I think `@SWG\SecurityScheme` for Basic auth only needs `securityDefinition` and `type="basic"` and should not have other attributes because they apply to other auth types. Can you try and see if it helps?

Comment: i Tried this and no changes. I also tried to put "security=[{"basicAuth"}], but no changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Annotations do not look right. Change `@SWG\SecurityScheme` to:

```
/**
 *  @SWG\SecurityScheme(
  *      securityDefinition="basicAuth",
  *      type="basic"
  *  )
  */
```

(without the `name` and `scheme` attributes), and change the `security` in `@SWG\Get` as follows:

```
/**
 * @SWG\Get(
 *     ...
 *     security = {{"basicAuth": {}}},
 *     ...
```

Comment: It works , but i have to underline the weird array type that is very ambiguious in the swagger-php document. That just tells « var array » for the property « security » in swg\get classe.